# Finding Screen Resolution Creates Thread Issues

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am trying to find the resolution of the monitor which I have done before easily but all of a sudden when I try to use it here it produces:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ''
accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Here is the code for my project:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Global Variables/Objects
    int SelectedTool = 1, WindowWidth, WindowHeight; //Here I create the variables 
    bool isMouseDown = false;
    Pen UserPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);
    Graphics CanvasGraphics;
    Point LastMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);

    //Initialize Components
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Find Screen Resolution
        WindowWidth = Screen.GetBounds(Form1.ActiveForm).X; //Problem Occurs Here
        WindowHeight = Screen.GetBounds(Form1.ActiveForm).Y; // And Here

            //Set Siz    
            Form1.ActiveForm.MaximumSize = new Size(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);

            //Create Graphics Object
            CanvasGraphics = canvas.CreateGraphics();
            CanvasGraphics.Clear(Color.White);

            //Start Threads
            Painter.RunWorkerAsync();
            Updater.RunWorkerAsync();

            label1.Text = Form1.ActiveForm.Location.X.ToString();
        }
```

The problem occurs when I change the values of `int WindowWidth` & `int WindowHeight` to `Screen.GetBounds(Form1.ActiveForm).X or Y`

I have also tried other ways of finding the resolution and none work. I think I have done something wrong that has caused this error somewhere but the reason behind the problem is beyond me.

After being changed:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Resize Window
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.Size = new Size(WindowWidth, WindowHeight); //Doesn't Work
        }
        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) //Form Activated
        {
        WindowWidth = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size.Width;
        WindowHeight = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size.Height;
        }
```

Comment: Form is not yet Initialized completely That means it is not active till now and you are trying to find the height and width. Try this on `Form_activated()` event

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, that would be the `Shown` event of the form, which is raised once only, immediately after the form is displayed for the first time.

Comment: It's a small thing but accessing a static member on a derived type is just wrong.  `ActiveForm` is a static property of the `Form` class so it should be called on the `Form` class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: you are absolutely correct `Shown` will be the right event as it only calls once. Now I cannot edit my comment. :D

Comment: Alright this works! I just figured it out. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor the form is not shown yet so the `Form.ActiveForm` is likely not your form. Secondly, use `Screen.WorkingArea` instead, unless you want to ignore the taskbar, etc.

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    Size resolution = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size;
}
```